# Between 2 electrically charged plates, can the speed of particle depend on distance between the plates? (Refer to image)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance

[image]

Now I understand that $\text{work}=KE$ and this will give the formula for speed as $$v=\sqrt{\frac{2qV}{m}}$$ My question is can’t the $V$ be replaced by $Ed$ since $V=E/d$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Between 2 electrically charged plates, can the speed of particle depend on distance between the plates?

If the initial position and velocity of the particle are known, then the velocity at any point $P$ can be calculated (assuming classical dynamics). However, if you have multiple particles, and they have different initial conditions, then one cannot say that at a given distance from one of the plates, all the particles will have the same velocity.

[How did the Helium nucleus get there? You might have an easier time calculating the velocity of an electron that began at the negative plate with 0 velocity. ;-)]

> can't the $V$ be replaced by $Ed$ since $V=\frac{E}{d}$

Yes.